# slideDown jQuery function doesn't slide in IE9

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've got a weird problem with jQuery x WP in IE9. Here's a codepen, that works (http://codepen.io/crs1138/pen/kfgLo), however the same code doesn't work on the site (http://coachingxconsulting.com/dev/services/). No warning or errors in console. It works fine in all other browser apart IE9 (I don't need it for any older IE than 9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what it is triping you over.

```
 #nav { -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (GradientType=0, startColorstr=#FFFFFF, endColorstr=#00ABCC)"; }
```

Add this in your head section or seperated css file that is only for IE9:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #nav { filter: none; }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right that it's the MS filter that's causing the trouble, however I don't seem to be able to sort it out using the style you posted. I suppose I could use a repeated image instead of the filter.

Comment: Yes that will do the trick. Since the filter applies something like overflow: hidden and it's messing your logic when used for a container, that has a drop-down.